# React Router - "A <Router> may have only one child element" error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

In my React app, I'd like to connect my main router to Redux so I can access some values stored there, but I'm getting the error `"A <Router> may have only one child element"`. I've seen others with this problem, but the solutions always involve wrapping the routes in a `<div>` or a `<Switch>`, which I have done... I'm not quite sure how to fix it in this circumstance.

Ideally, this is what I would like to achieve - this is `routes/index.jsx`:

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router"
import AppContainer from "containers/App"
import SignInRouter from "./signin-router"
import SignUpRouter from "./signup-router"
import DashboardRouter from "./dashboard-router"
import NotFound from "../components/NotFound"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return { state }
    }

const routes = (props) => (
    <AppContainer>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SignInRouter} />
            <Route path={`/${props.state.state.signupPath}`} component={SignUpRouter} />
            <Route path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}`} component={DashboardRouter} />
            <Route path="/*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </AppContainer>
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(routes)
```

originally, this was set up like so:

```
const routes = (
    <AppContainer>
        // etc...
    </AppContainer>
)
```

but once I changed it to a function - `const routes = (props) => (...)` - it broke.

I'm a little miffed, because I was able to successfully accomplish this with some of my other routers in the app - for example, here is `routes/dashboard-router.jsx`:

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router"
import DashboardContainer from "../containers/App/dashboard-container"
import DashboardIndex from "../components/Dashboard"
import Agendas from "../components/Dashboard/agendas"
import Meetings from "../components/Dashboard/meetings"
import Groups from "../components/Dashboard/groups"
import Account from "../components/Dashboard/account"
import NotFound from "../components/NotFound"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return { state }
    }

const DashboardRouter = (props) => (
    <DashboardContainer>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}`} component={DashboardIndex} />
            <Route exact path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}/agendas`} component={Agendas} />
            <Route exact path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}/meetings`} component={Meetings} />
            <Route exact path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}/groups`} component={Groups} />
            <Route exact path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}/account`} component={Account} />
            <Route path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}/*`} component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </DashboardContainer>
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(DashboardRouter)
```

and that works perfectly.

Why is this a problem in my top-level router, but not in the lower-level routers? And what can I do to resolve this?

For additional reference, here's the `AppContainer`, which wraps the `<Switch>` in the router in question:

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import Header from "components/Header"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return { state }
    }

const AppContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header
                isAuthenticated={props.state.session.isAuthenticated} />
            <main>
                {props.children}
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AppContainer))
```

To Robert Farley's comment, this is a React/Phoenix app, scaffolded by using https://github.com/reph-stack/reph.  Here is the way `<StaticRouter>` is referenced in this app's structure:

`containers/index.jsx`:

```
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import createStoreAndRouter from "store"

const Index = (props) => {
    const { store, router } = createStoreAndRouter(props)

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {router}
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default Index
```

`store/index.js`:

```
import React from "react"
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux"
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from "react-router-redux"
import { Route, StaticRouter } from "react-router"
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"
import createMemoryHistory from "history/createMemoryHistory"
import thunkMW from "redux-thunk"
import routes from "routes"
import reducers from "reducers"
import WSActions from "actions/ws"

export default function createStoreAndRouter(props) {
    return (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window === "object")
        ? createForBrowser()
        : createForServer(props)
}

const createForBrowser = () => {
    const devToolsExt = typeof window.devToolsExtension !== "undefined"
        ? window.devToolsExtension()
        : f => f
    const history = createBrowserHistory()
    const store = createStore(
        reducers,
        window.__INITIAL_STATE__,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunkMW),
            applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history)),
            devToolsExt
        )
    )
    store.dispatch(WSActions.init())
    const router = <ConnectedRouter
    history={history}
    >
    {routes}
    </ConnectedRouter>
    return { store, router }
}

const createForServer = (props) => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    const store = createStore(
        reducers,
        props.initial_state,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunkMW),
            applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history))
        )
    )
    const router = <StaticRouter
    context={{}}
    location={props.location}
    history={history}
    >
    {routes}
    </StaticRouter>
    return { store, router }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the use of `<Router>` in your app?

Comment: You should not use Switch outside of a Router. Line #45 from Switch.js:   Switch.prototype.componentWillMount = function componentWillMount() {
    (0, _invariant2.default)(this.context.router, 'You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>');
  };

Comment: @RobertFarley I've added info about the use of `<Router>`.

Comment: It's actually the `<StaticRouter>`...

Comment: @KyleRichardson sorry, it is ultimately wrapped in a `<StaticRouter>` - see the code I added.

Comment: @skwidbreth In your `createForServer` and `createForBrowser` functions, I don't see where the `routes` that are being passed to the `StaticRouter` constructor are coming from. Try modifying those functions to return a function that accepts the routes and then returns the new `StaticRouter` with the provided routes. Looks like you're creating the `StaticRouter` with no routes to me. Unless I'm not seeing something.

Comment: @KyleRichardson thanks for having a look. Yeah - I'm not 100% familiar with this context yet - first time using this particular app setup.

Comment: @skwidbreth Np, if you have any further questions I will try to answer them!

Comment: have you tried using `<withRouter>` and add your `<Switch>` inside `<div>`

Comment: @KyleRichardson - this is interesting - I found that `router.props.children` is evaluating as `[Function: routes]` in the broken code - it should be a React node - `$$typeof': Symbol(react.element)...` etc. - referring to the file that I'm trying to change - `routes/index.jsx`.  Any thoughts on what could alleviate that?  As in, make sure that gets parsed as a React node rather than a function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wrap your routes in a router if you want to render them in a function :

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const routes = (props) => (
    <AppContainer>
      <BrowserRouter>  
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SignInRouter} />
          <Route path={`/${props.state.state.signupPath}`} component={SignUpRouter} />
          <Route path={`/${props.state.state.dashboardPath}`} component={DashboardRouter} />
          <Route path="/*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AppContainer>
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that I didn't provide enough information in my question... this app uses server-side rendering, so `<BrowserRouter>` won't work - it throws the error `"Browser history needs a DOM"`